# Connect TCPIP clashes with QT Connect

Tags: c++, qt, tcp

I am having a problem with the connect function for TCPIP because QT has a similar function connect.

> no matching function for call to MainWindow::connect(SOCKET&, sockaddr*, unsigned int)

Can someone help me with this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to disambiguate between the global function and the one in `MainWindow`, you can use the scope resolution operator:

```
::connect(/* ... arguments go here ... */)
```

The use of `::` here tells the compiler to look at the global scope for the function, rather than using the standard name lookup technique that would find the one in the class first.